# OMP: Different Outputs in Serial and Parallel Versions

Tags: c, openmp

I am trying to run matrix multiplication program using OMP. I am getting different outputs in Serial and Parallel Versions. I am trying with just a 3* 3 Matrix for testing.

My Parallel code is:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NRA 3//62                 /* number of rows in matrix A */
#define NCA 3//15                 /* number of columns in matrix A */
#define NCB 3//7                  /* number of columns in matrix B */

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
int tid, nthreads, i, j, k, chunk;
double  a[NRA][NCA],           /* matrix A to be multiplied */
    b[NCA][NCB],           /* matrix B to be multiplied */
    c[NRA][NCB];           /* result matrix C */

chunk = 10;                    /* set loop iteration chunk size */

/*** Spawn a parallel region explicitly scoping all variables ***/
#pragma omp parallel shared(a,b,c,nthreads,chunk) private(tid,i,j,k)
  {
  tid = omp_get_thread_num();
  if (tid == 0)
    {
    nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    printf("Starting matrix multiple example with %d threads\n",nthreads);
    printf("Initializing matrices...\n");
    }
  /*** Initialize matrices ***/
  #pragma omp for schedule (static, chunk) 
  for (i=0; i<NRA; i++)
    for (j=0; j<NCA; j++)
      a[i][j]= i+j;
  #pragma omp for schedule (static, chunk)
  for (i=0; i<NCA; i++)
    for (j=0; j<NCB; j++)
      b[i][j]= i*j;
  #pragma omp for schedule (static, chunk)
  for (i=0; i<NRA; i++)
    for (j=0; j<NCB; j++)
      c[i][j]= 0;

  /*** Do matrix multiply sharing iterations on outer loop ***/
  /*** Display who does which iterations for demonstration purposes ***/
  printf("Thread %d starting matrix multiply...\n",tid);
  #pragma omp for schedule (static, chunk)
  for (i=0; i<NRA; i++)    
    {
    printf("Thread=%d did row=%d\n",tid,i);
    for(j=0; j<NCB; j++)       
      for (k=0; k<NCA; k++)
        c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
    }
  }   /*** End of parallel region ***/

/*** Print results ***/

printf("******************************************************\n");
printf("Result Matrix:\n");
for (i=0; i<NRA; i++)
  {
  for (j=0; j<NCB; j++) 
    printf("%6.2f   ", a[i][j]);
  printf("\n"); 
  }
printf("******************************************************\n");

printf("******************************************************\n");
printf("Result Matrix:\n");
for (i=0; i<NRA; i++)
  {
  for (j=0; j<NCB; j++) 
    printf("%6.2f   ", b[i][j]);
  printf("\n"); 
  }
printf("******************************************************\n");
printf("******************************************************\n");
printf("Result Matrix:\n");
for (i=0; i<NRA; i++)
  {
  for (j=0; j<NCB; j++) 
    printf("%6.2f   ", c[i][j]);
  printf("\n"); 
  }
printf("******************************************************\n");
printf ("Done.\n");

}
```

For Serial version I have just commented the line:

```
#pragma omp for schedule (static, chunk)
```

Output of my parallel version is:

> Starting matrix multiple example with 12 threads Initializing
>   matrices... Thread 0 starting matrix multiply... Thread 8 starting
>   matrix multiply... Thread 6 starting matrix multiply... Thread 9
>   starting matrix multiply... Thread 5 starting matrix multiply...
>   Thread 1 starting matrix multiply... Thread 4 starting matrix
>   multiply... Thread 7 starting matrix multiply... Thread 10 starting
>   matrix multiply... Thread 3 starting matrix multiply... Thread 2
>   starting matrix multiply... Thread=0 did row=0 Thread=0 did row=1
>   Thread=0 did row=2 Thread 11 starting matrix multiply...
>   ****************************************************** Result Matrix:
>     0.00     1.00     2.00
>     1.00     2.00     3.00
>     2.00     3.00     4.00
>
> ---
>
> ****************************************************** Result Matrix:
>     0.00     0.00     0.00
>     0.00     1.00     2.00
>     0.00     2.00     4.00
>
> ---
>
> ****************************************************** Result Matrix:
>     0.00     5.00    10.00
>     0.00     8.00    16.00
>     0.00    11.00    22.00
>   ****************************************************** Done.

Output of my serial version is this:

> Starting matrix multiple example with 12 threads Initializing
>   matrices... Thread 0 starting matrix multiply... Thread 3 starting
>   matrix multiply... Thread 5 starting matrix multiply... Thread 11
>   starting matrix multiply... Thread 1 starting matrix multiply...
>   Thread 10 starting matrix multiply... Thread 2 starting matrix
>   multiply... Thread 9 starting matrix multiply... Thread 7 starting
>   matrix multiply... Thread 8 starting matrix multiply... Thread 4
>   starting matrix multiply... Thread 6 starting matrix multiply...
>   ****************************************************** Result Matrix:
>     0.00     1.00     2.00
>     1.00     2.00     3.00
>     2.00     3.00     4.00
>
> ---
>
> ****************************************************** Result Matrix:
>     0.00     0.00     0.00
>     0.00     1.00     2.00
>     0.00     2.00     4.00
>
> ---
>
> ****************************************************** Result Matrix:
>     0.00    60.00   120.00
>     0.00    96.00   192.00
>     0.00   132.00   264.00
>   ****************************************************** Done.

How can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. In Serial version, I was not commenting properly. I was ignoring the line:

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(a,b,c,nthreads,chunk) private(tid,i,j,k)
```